# How to reset error in the form after submit in angular by angular way?

Tags: angular

I set error validation manually in my form, using `setErrors`.

The problem is the error is not clear when the submit happens.

I also don't want to go though all the controls and set the errors to null- because it cancel other errors on the control.

only one time I set the error the next time I don't set the error. I don't want to remove it myself I need to some function from angular to update the validation by default.

I try to add: `{ updateOn: "submit" }` doesn't clear the error. angular should know that he doesn't have any validations. so the second time it need to remove the error. so this is not happens.

[This is my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-frost-jz81w?file=/src/app/app.component.ts). How to update/trigger the form validation so the error will be remove?

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <label>
        First Name:
        <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" required />
        <div *ngIf="firstname.hasError('foo')">foo error!!</div>
        <div *ngIf="firstname.hasError('required')">required</div>
      </label>

      <label>
        Last Name:
        <input type="text" formControlName="lastName" />
      </label>

      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "CodeSandbox";

  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(""),
    lastName: new FormControl("")
  });

  get firstname() {
    return this.profileForm.controls["firstName"];
  }

  showFooError = true;

  onSubmit() {
    console.log("in submit");

    if (this.showFooError) {
      this.profileForm.controls["firstName"].setErrors({ foo: true });
      this.showFooError = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using setErrors? can you please explain the case that made you need to use it?

Comment: I add error in field manually. and I want angular to remove it because I have no validation - so no error should be exist.

Comment: Bear with me please, Why didn't you use the validators? if you use setErrors, then I believe you have some kind of validation in your form.

Comment: I want to use another validator executer. I can match between the fields and the error validation reports. so this is why

Comment: I don't think there's a way to let Angular know that it should clear the errors unless you use custom validators.

Answer (score 0):

`updateOn: 'blur'` and  `updateOn: 'submit'` are the options we were really craving for while working with Angular `Forms`.

So try this:

**app.component.ts**

```js
this.userForm = this.fb.group(
  {
    name: ["", [Validators.required]],
    email: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
  },
  { updateOn: "submit" }
);
```

or

```js
this.userForm = this.fb.group(
  {
    name: ["", [Validators.required]],
    email: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
  },
  { updateOn: "blur" }
);
```

For more information look at this article: [Angular Form Validation on Blur and Submit](https://fiyazhasan.me/angular-forms-validation-updateon-blur/)

Comment: `{ updateOn: "submit" }` doesn't clear the error. angular should know that he doesn't have any validations. so the second time it need to remove the error. so this is not happens.

Comment: no. I don't use angular validations. I don't have `required` or anything. I just set the error in the field and I want angular to remove the error after it validations.

Comment: this is not what I mean in my question. please read my question

Comment: Ok, I'm checking. wait please

Comment: I created a sample of your project here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fncogu?file=src/app/app.component.ts If you want you should use custom error

Comment: The fooError is not one of the angular standard `Validations.error` and angular dosen't know when it is satisfied to remove it